# Comparing files with C

Tags: c, file

I'm trying to write a code that compares two files and shows if they are equal or not

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    
    FILE *f1, *f2;
    int diff = 0;
    char c1, c2, name_f1[100], name_f2[100];

    printf("File1: ");
    fgets(name_f1, 100, stdin);

    printf("File2: ");
    fgets(name_f2, 100, stdin);

    f1 = fopen(name_f1, "r+");
    f2 = fopen(name_f2, "r+");
    
    do{
        c1 = fgetc(f1);
        c2 = fgetc(f2);

        if (c1 != c2){
            diff = 1;
        }
    }while(c1 != EOF && c2 != EOF);

    fclose(f1);
    fclose(f2);

    if(diff==1){
        printf("Files are different");
    }else{
        printf("Files are the same");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But it keeps telling me that they are the same, even if they are not and I have no idea why
Also if fopen is just for reading ("r") it return segmentation fault, which I also have no idea why is happening

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Is the first part of the files perhaps identical? If you hit one EOF before the other, they have different sizes and are by definition not the same. You can check this up front as well and avoid the loop in that case. Also, not related to your problem, you can break out of the loop as soon as you see a difference.

Comment: **Always**, really **always** check if `fopen` fails. There is absolutely no excuse of not doing it.

Comment: You might want to study for inspiration the source code of [GNU diffutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/). You need to read the documentation of your C compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the behavior you're describing might suggest the files you're trying to open don't exist, since "r" returns null if the file doesn't exist but "r+" creates a file*, this does seem to explain the segmentation fault error.
therefor it's also reasonable you're program returns the files are identical, since both created files will be empty.
perhaps you're path isn't correct?

Tip: always check for `fopen` success and exit on failure

*as seen here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/file-opening-modesr-versus-r/